# How to sort Data from WebClient Response

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, webclient

I have a WebClient like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(myurl));
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
}
```

Handler:

```
private void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());
}
```

And that's what I've get:

```
    {"out_error":"",
"out_id":4274,
"out_device_hash":"7a8e4f7a264a6afb38cfadb6b50e7a45c58d226b",
"out_device_name":"Unnamed device",
"out_uname":"User Name",
"token":"e1c063d16fee7bb8912099034f67c2d17a8f45c3"}
```

The question is how can I get those strings sorted to separate strings like in xml:

```
string error = out_error;
string id = out_id;
```

and so on... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Json parser.

Using [Json.Net](https://json.codeplex.com/)

```
var dict1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(e.Result);
```

Using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var dict2 = new JavaScriptSerializer()
            .Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(e.Result);


string id = dict1["out_id"];
```